# Javascript Regex replace (remove) <br> tag at the start of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

how can i only remove `<br>` at the start of the string?

from:

```
'<br><br><br>My Text<br>is here<br>'
```

to:

```
'My Text<br>is here<br>'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with **[regex `/^(<br\s*\/?>)+/`](https://regex101.com/r/aQ2hK7/2)**

```js
var str='<br><br><br>My Text<br>is here<br>';

alert(str.replace(/^(<br\s*\/?>)+/,''))
```

Comment: I'd use `(<br\s*\/?>)` just to be sure.

Comment: @BenHsieh : glad to help

Comment: This does not remove the 3rd `<br>` in this string `<br><br> <br>`  ... Notice the space after 2 <br>s

Comment: @umair he just want to remove the br tags at the beginning

Comment: @PranavCBalan I am also talking about the tags `<br><br> <br>` in the beginning ...

Comment: @umair 
`str.replace(/^(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/,'')`